# Drill down input lag in openscad in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I have two installations, one is Laptop Lenovo X1 Yoga, the other is Desktop PC Ryzen 5 5600X, ASUS TUF Gaming X570-Plus mainboard, 32GB RAM.
On both systems software is the same level, but
only on Desktop sometimes i experience huge input lags (up to 2 seconds) in openscad.
The lag already happens in a complete empty document.

During that period system monitoring doesn't show any load (CPU <10%, no network, no storage load). After reboot, i have a good chance that system is back to normal.

Also, the lag is only in openscad and no other program.

Any suggestions, how to narrow down this problem?

A: swap is on, but not used in such situation.